# How can a wrap a setValue call from the React useState hook and maintain the same type signature?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

If I have code like `const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");`, the type is `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>`.

I want to have something `const wrappedSetValue = (value: string) => setValue(value.toUpperCase());`. How can I write that so it maintains the same type signature of `setValue`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof` TS keyword to infer the type of `setValue` and annotate it on `wrappedSetValue`.

```js
const wrappedSetValue: typeof setValue = (value: string) => setValue(value.toUpperCase());
```

To be honest, that's kinda cheat cus `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>` is in fact a type alias that boils down to

```
(value: string | ((s: string) => string)) => void;
```

Thus above implementation only covers half of the type signature.

I'm not sure this is what you want, but in order to fulfill the signature declaration, you should also implement the other half that allows passing in function as param:

```js
const wrappedSetValue: typeof setValue = (value: string | ((s: string) => string)) => 
  typeof value == 'string' ? setValue(value.toUpperCase()) : setValue(value);
```